# How to import product include entity_id?

Tags: magento2, import-products

I want to import **products** with the existing `id`. ex: I have products which `id` start from **200**. How can I import those products to `magento product table` which will start from **200** also?

Comment: you want to create new product using csv right ?

Comment: I think you could set auto increment value in  product table to 200 and then perform the import, make sure id is not already available